# document.location.reload(true) not working in ie9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reload

I'm forcing a page to reload from the server with `document.location.reload(true);` and it all works fine in Chrome but for some reason it doesn't in internet explorer. The page refreshes but it stills loads with the old data.

Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
location.reload();
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/heUtf/

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be caused by incorrect DOC Mode in IE. 
To verify hit F12 (dev tools) and see which Document Mode is set. If it's set to Quirks or IE 7 it may be messing with your javascript.

One way you can force the Doc mode to the currently available mode in the browser is specifying the following in the web.config.

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

More related info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh779632.aspx

Comment: Just for those readers not familiar, the web.config is for IIS (and related servers). Different web servers and applications will use other ways to specify this header.